# Using Irreducible Group Characters to Count nth Roots of Group Elements

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $\tau_n(g)=|\lbrace h\in G: h^n=g\rbrace|$.

Let $\chi_i,1\leq i\leq r$ be the distinct complex irreducible characters of a finite group $G$, and let $\gamma_n(\chi_i)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_i(g^n)$.

Prove that $\tau_n(g)=\sum_{i=1}^r\gamma_n(\chi_i)\chi_i(g)$.

I have been poking away at this for a couple days, and can't seem to get anywhere. I have manually checked that it works in groups like $Q_8$ and $S_4$, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why this is true, outside of the easy cases like $n = 1$ or where raising each element to the $n^{th}$ power induces an automorphism of sets, i.e $\lbrace g: g\in G\rbrace=\lbrace g^n:g\in G\rbrace$.

I'm most curious as to WHY this works. It seems so nice that it must have a simple solution hidden somewhere.

Comment: for what $\chi$ is $\sum_g \chi(g^{n}) = 0$ ?

Comment: You're missing a $1/|G|$ factor. And the proof follows by noting (1) it's value depends only on the conjugacy class, so it's a combination of characters, and (2) we can find the coefficients of those characters with the inner product.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the $1/|G|$! It's been edited.

I noticed that it was a class function, but I don't see how you get the coefficients given in the problem by taking the inner product. To be more precise, I know you can get the coefficients abstractly as:

$$
\tau_n(g)=\sum_i^r \langle \tau_n,\chi_i\rangle \chi_i(g)
$$

Which would imply that we want to show $\langle \tau_n,\chi_i\rangle=\gamma_n(\chi_i)$, however I don't see where the sum comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, the claim follows if we show $\langle \tau_n,\chi_i\rangle=\gamma_n(\chi_i)$. Things become a bit clearer if we rename the slightly misleadingly named summation variable $g$ to $h$:

$$\gamma_n(\chi_i)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{h\in G}\chi_i(h^n)=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\tau_n(g)\chi_i(g)\;.$$